# 未来につなぐ: Precise meaning? Fuzzy marketing buzzword?

Tags: translation, phrases, copywriting

未来につなぐ

Does this phrase have a precise meaning, a meaning that can be translated into precise English? Or is this simply a positive-sounding but vague trendy marketing phrase?

I see for example the following from company and government websites, usually as a title or a motto:

1. 未来につなぐ環境戦略
2. 未来につなぐ森づくり
3. 未来につなぐ松下幸之助の精神
4. 未来につなぐわらごはん

But, for example 1 above, "Environmental Strategy Connecting to the Future,"  sounds vague and a bit silly, not very natural. "Linking to the Future" sounds a bit better but still odd.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's a marketing phrase. コーポレートスローガン (corporate slogan).
See [企業のスローガン・企業コピーまとめ](http://matome.naver.jp/odai/2126276350931073501)

> 未来につなぐ環境戦略 > not natural (not colloquial)
>   未来につなぐ**ための**環境戦略 > natural

e.g.
***Talk:***
「[本日]{ほんじつ}は*未来につなぐための環境戦略*について[討議]{とうぎ}しましょう」

***TV Commercial:***
「*未来につなぐ環境戦略*」(with something BGM)