# Meaning of ~を繋げ in this context?

Tags: meaning, words

I have a quick question about meaning of を繋げ in the following:

> 『何があろうと、主の未来を繋げ』

From what I do know, "繋" means to connect/tie/fasten, but I can't make sense of it when I try to incorporate it into a translation of the above sentence. "Connect the future of the kings", "tie the future of the kings" etc. That doesn't make sense to me.

So I'm thinking either I'm misunderstanding the nuance here, or 未来を繋げ is some sort of expression or set phrase I don't know about. If someone can clear this up I would be extremely grateful!

Answer (score 3):

Here 繋ぐ means "to retain" or "not to lose". It's used figuratively to keep connection between 主's present and 主's future. Similarly, 命を繋ぐ means "to survive", 希望を繋ぐ/望みを繋ぐ means "to keep having what little hope one has (in a very bad situation)", 明日へ繋ぐXY means something like "XY for tomorrow" (marketing phrase).

未来に繋ぐ/未来を繋ぐ is also a phrase sometimes used in company slogans and such. See: [未来につなぐ: Precise meaning? Fuzzy marketing buzzword?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22896/5010)

Comment: Ah I see, so it would mean "preserve the future" here, thanks for your quick response!